# how to use firebase phone aut on expo (react native 2022)

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm new to expo, and I'm trying to make an application with login by firebase authentication by phone, however I can't find enough documentation
Has anyone successfully implemented firebase authentication in expo (SDK 44) without ejecting
I found this tutorial but it works only with firebase 8, and the current one is firebase 9.8.4
currently it doesn't work anymore

https://arjayosma.medium.com/set-up-firebase-phone-authentication-in-expo-sdk-37-without-ejecting-8a472460b1cf

Answer (score 1):

Firebase phone authentication is not possible out of the box using the Firebase JS SDK. This because an Application Verifier object (reCAPTCHA) is needed as an additional security measure to verify that the user is real and not a bot in Firebase JS SDK workflow.

FirebaseRecaptcha in expo was used to compensate for this object. However, This module will no longer be available in SDK 48 . Apps can be built migrating to React native firebase

Answer (score 0):

This works for me for the latest one:

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import useAuth from "../../../hooks/useAuth";
import { auth, app } from "../../../firebase";
import { PhoneAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import {
  FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal,
  FirebaseRecaptchaBanner,
} from "expo-firebase-recaptcha";


const Component = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [phoneNumberValue, setPhoneNumberValue] = useState("");
    const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = useState("30");
  
    const formatPhoneNumber = (newValue) => {
        const numericValue = newValue.replace(/\D/g, "");

        setPhoneNumberValue(numericValue);
    };


    const AuthWithPhone = async () => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const formattedPhone = `+${countryCode}` + phoneNumberValue;

            const phoneProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(auth);
            const verifiedId = await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
                formattedPhone,
                recaptchaVerifier.current
            );

            setUserAuth((prevUserAuth) => ({
                ...prevUserAuth,
                phoneNumber: formattedPhone,
                verificationId: verifiedId,
                message: "Verification code has been sent to your phone.",
            }));

            setLoading(false);
            navigation.navigate("OTPVerification");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Verification error");
            setUserAuth((prevUserAuth) => ({
                ...prevUserAuth,
                message: `Error: ${err.message}`,
            }));
        }
    };
    return (
        <>
            <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
              ref={recaptchaVerifier}
              firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}
              attemptInvisibleVerification={attemptInvisibleVerification}
            />
                <TextInput
                  value={phoneNumberValue}
                  placeholder="6912345678"
                  keyboardType="phone-pad"
                  autoCompleteType="tel"
                  onFocus={() => setInputBorder("black")}
                  onChangeText={(value) => formatPhoneNumber(value)}
                  }/>
                
      </>
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```